# zsh shell problem specifically when I am trying to get output

Tags: shell, zsh

````
read -p "Enter your name: " NAME
echo "Hello $NAME, nice to meet you".```


In terminal:
````

ks@USER Desktop % ./script.sh
./script.sh:read:18: -p: no coprocess
Hello , nice to meet you.

```
[picture of the problem ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpVri.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ZSH `-p` doesn't mean prompt as in Bash. See `man zshbuiltins`:

```
   read [ -rszpqAclneE ] [ -t [ num ] ] [ -k [ num ] ] [ -d delim ]
   (...)
   -p     Input is read from the coprocess.
```

To get a prompt with ZSH implementation of `read`:

```
$ read "?Enter your name: " NAME
Enter your name: myname
$ echo $NAME
myname
```